# Non-stop increasing width after setting proportional sized boxes in js

Tags: javascript, html

I tried setting each box' height to be proportional to the set width. The width is in percent, different depending on browser width. it works great when the box' width is less than 100%. Once they are 100% however, they wont stop expanding when the browser's width changes. Even the container "games" expands, and setting a fixed width doesn't help. How do I fix this?

```js
window.onload = boxResize;
window.onresize = boxResize;
var i; //Variable for loop, not important.
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

//Sets the width of each box depending on the browser's width
function boxResize(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 1400){
        boxResizeF(0.333);
    }
    else if(window.innerWidth <= 1400 && window.innerWidth > 980){
        boxResizeF(0.5);
    }
    else if(window.innerWidth <= 980){
        boxResizeF(1); //This is where problems start to occur!
    }
}

//Resizes each box so that the height is proportional to its width.
function boxResizeF(percentage){
    var gamesEl = document.getElementById("games"); //This is the container of the "box" element.
    var gamesElWidth = gamesEl.offsetWidth; //Width of container
    
    for(i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
        var boxWidth = gamesElWidth * percentage; //Set the width of each box in percent.
        box[i].style.width = boxWidth + "px"; //Set width
        var boxRatio = 9/16;
        var boxHeight = boxWidth * boxRatio;
        box[i].style.height = boxHeight + "px"; //Set height
    }
}
```

```css
.box{
    display: table; float: left; box-sizing: border-box;
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#games{
    display: table;
    width: 80%; height: auto;
    margin: auto;
        border: 1px solid blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px){
    #games{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="games">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;`?

```js
window.onload = boxResize;
window.onresize = boxResize;
var i; //Variable for loop, not important.
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

//Sets the width of each box depending on the browser's width
function boxResize() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 1400) {
    boxResizeF(0.333);
  } else if (window.innerWidth <= 1400 && window.innerWidth > 980) {
    boxResizeF(0.5);
  } else if (window.innerWidth <= 980) {
    boxResizeF(1); //This is where problems start to occur!
  }
}

//Resizes each box so that the height is proportional to its width.
function boxResizeF(percentage) {
  var gamesEl = document.getElementById("games"); //This is the container of the "box" element.
  var gamesElWidth = gamesEl.offsetWidth; //Width of container

  for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    var boxWidth = gamesElWidth * percentage; //Set the width of each box in percent.
    box[i].style.width = boxWidth + "px"; //Set width
    var boxRatio = 9 / 16;
    var boxHeight = boxWidth * boxRatio;
    box[i].style.height = boxHeight + "px"; //Set height
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: table;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#games {
  display: table;
  width: 80vw;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  #games {
    width: 100vw;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="games">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JonathanFogelström have you tried 100vw? viewport (1 = 1% for current window width) and also 100vh for viewport height, 1 = 1% current window height

Comment: This works really well, is there a way to make the width and height relative to the parent?

Comment: @JonathanFogelström % are related to parent. REF: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/width/

Comment: In that case i could only set the width and height of the box to be proportional to the parent which isn't my intention. i want the box' height & width to use the 16:9 ratio

Comment: @JonathanFogelström use like 16vw and 9vw? since vw or vh will caculated to px so use height as 9vw and width as 16vw (or 18/32 etc...)

Comment: I tried that when you mentioned vh & vw earlier but as you said it's only relative to the window and not the parent.

Comment: @JonathanFogelström hm take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css

Comment: This solves all my issues, thanks for the help Daniel!